# Meaning of $(\mathbf{\Omega}\cdot\nabla)^2\mathbf{u}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

My lecturer has the following equation for the inertial waves in a rotating fluid:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\nabla ^2\mathbf{u} + 4(\mathbf{\Omega}\cdot\nabla)^2\mathbf{u} = 0$$

where $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t)$ is a vector field (velocity of the fluid) and $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is a constant vector representing the rotation of the fluid. I know that $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian operator, so for a three dimensional vector field $\phi$ in Cartesian coordinates,

$$\nabla ^2 \phi = \left(\frac{\partial^2 \phi_x}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_x}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_x}{\partial z^2},\frac{\partial^2 \phi_y}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_y}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_y}{\partial z^2},\frac{\partial^2 \phi_z}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_z}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi_z}{\partial z^2}\right)$$ and that $u\cdot v$ is the dot product of $u$ and $v$.

But I don't understand what $(\mathbf{\Omega}\cdot\nabla)^2\mathbf{u}$ means.

Is it $\mathbf{\Omega}\cdot(\nabla^2\mathbf{u})$? Or $\mathbf{\Omega}^2\cdot(\nabla^2\mathbf{u})$? Or $\nabla^2(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{\Omega})$?

Comment: From a purely mathematical point of view I could give you an answer, which corresponds to none of your options. But you might find it 'safer' if you pose this question on Physics SE where people use these models and know any particular notational quirks (of which, let's be honest, physicists are notorious!)

Comment: The answer I was going to give is what Ivo has written out below.

Comment: @SimonS you make a good point, the trouble is I'm an engineer and we are even more notorious with our notation! And that's fine, I doubted that any of my options were correct anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write ${\bf \Omega} = (\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\Omega_3)$. The operator ${\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla = \Omega_1 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\Omega_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\Omega_3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ acts in $\phi$ by $$({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)\phi = \Omega_1 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\Omega_2\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}+\Omega_3\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z},$$ the same going for a vector $\bf u$ instead of  a function $\phi$. For $({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)^2$ you do this twice, we will have some product and chain rules in there, as in: $$({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)^2\phi = \Omega_1 \frac{\partial (({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)\phi)}{\partial x}+\Omega_2\frac{\partial(({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)\phi)}{\partial y}+\Omega_3\frac{\partial(({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)\phi)}{\partial z} = \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake in my question, $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}, t)$ is actually vector field, it's not a scalar field. So I'm assuming this doesn't make a fundamental difference to your answer, so $({\bf \Omega}\cdot \nabla)^2\phi$ is the same as you said but is a vector with 3 elements and $\phi$ is replaced by $\phi_x$, $\phi_y$ and $\phi_z$ in each element. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! You apply it to each component.